# How can I append to a terminal buffer in vimscript?

Tags: functions, terminal-buffer

I am trying to implement a vimscript function which appends to a terminal buffer. It works when I write this as a single mapping which uses the normal mode 'a' command to append:

```
nnoremap <Leader>glq :tabnew<CR>:terminal<CR>:set ft=instaflog<CR>als<CR>
```

But I want this in a function to make the code clearer. However, using `append()` or `insert()` I get the error stating that the terminal buffer is not modifiable, which I guess is strictly true, but every keypress is passed on to the terminal. So far, I have:

```
function! TerminalSomething() abort
  tabnew
  terminal
  set ft=instaflog
  startinsert
  execute "normal! Ayyy" 
endfunction
```

But the 'yyy' text doesn't appear; that execute line apparently does nothing for terminal buffers, even though it works for all other buffer types.

Comment: First thing I try when text is seemingly being ignored is to send it with `feedkeys()`.

Comment: Brilliant; `  call feedkeys("Als\<CR>")` works. Convert to answer so I can give you points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `feedkeys()`. What makes me think that<sup>*</sup> is the fact that you got the response you wanted when the command was included in a mapping. Looking at the first sentence of the [documentation for the function](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#feedkeys()):

> Characters in {string} are queued for processing *as if they come from a mapping* or were typed by the user.

(Emphasis is mine.)

So instead of

```
execute "normal! als"
```

...try...

```
call feedkeys("als\<CR>")
```

Be sure to read the docs as there are some important things to be aware of there such as the need to escape special keys/keycodes as is done here with `<CR>`.

*<sub>Besides the fact that whenever output seems to be ignored I usually try `feedkeys()` as a first step.</sub>

Comment: instead of 'whatever', I'd suggest ls\<CR> since that shows how to escape the enter you will need at the end to issue a terminal command, and it can be pasted in and tested directly.

Comment: There's also [`term_sendkeys()`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#term_sendkeys%28%29), not sure how that's different or why you'd use it over `feedkeys()`, but probably worth having a look.